# how to get as400 spool files to text in c#

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange, spool

I'm trying to code a console application to get the spool file from as400 to a different destination as a text file. I have been looking around but I haven't found a small code to start from there, I been searching around and haven't found anything close.

You guys have any idea or suggestion on how to start this?

Comment: I'm not sure about AS400, but on system z there is typically an FTP service that can be used to retrieve job spool files. Check with your system admin to find out which options are available for fetching job output. Once you know the options, you'll be better equipped to figure out how to handle the problem in C#.

Comment: If FTP is an option, it seems there is a good tutorial on using the AS400 FTP here: http://www.go4as400.com/FTP-SNDNETF-stream-file-STMF-in-as400/file_transfer.aspx?cid=22. It also seems like there are some classes to support FTP interaction in C#. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [CPYSPLF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/cpysplf.htm) and [CPYTOSTMF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/cpytostmf.htm) are good places to start.  There are also third-party tools like [SPLAMATIC/SPLCONVERT](http://www.gumbo.com/Licpgm/Spool-a-Matic.html) from Gumbo Software.  You can save the file to a shared IFS directory (mapped to a Windows drive) and have your c# program get it from there.

Comment: There are many different ways to go about this. I think we probably use 4 or 5 of them at my work.  Do you need to do this from a C# program or would it make sense to run a program on the IBM system that sends the spool file out instead?

Comment: Another way to approach this is to have your C# program use the cwbx.dll objects:  the AS400System class to log onto the system, and the Program class to issue a `CALL` command that would execute whatever RPG or CL program creates/copies the spool file.  You could also use the Command class if you want to execute commands like `CPYSPLF`.  That can be like writing a CL script in C# (which is not as insane as it might sound).

Comment: @Player1st Yes, I need to do this in c# I need to export the spool file into a text file. I'm still doing random stuff with the code but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: What can you do now on the AS400 from c#?

Comment: Are you using anything from C# to call AS400 programs currently? Your best best is to do like @Mike suggested and call a program already on the 400 to convert the spool file to a shared IFS directory. From that point, you can grab the file from that shared IFS directory in C#. I would recommend testing out both parts separately before you merge them into a single program. Figure out the command you need to run on the 400 by doing it manually in the green screen. Then, put a file in a shared directory and test pulling that into your program. At the end, you can put those together.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm using the API calls QUSRTVUS to get the spooledfile list and want to open a specific spooled file with information of the previous API call.
After getting the file list I create a new userspace with QUSCRTUS. Then I want to open the file with QSPOPNSP but that is my problem.
[Sourcecode to open a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMXl.png)

After opening the file I would read the content with QSPGETSP which copies the file in the userspace where I could read it.

That's the plan but without opening the file the rest doesn't work.
I get the error directly when calling the API, this is not an error message during the work of the call. Changing the parameters don't change the error message.

Maybe someone has a hint?

UPDATE: I found out the mistake. Despite the misleading error message, it was an authorization problem. I wasn't allowed to call the APIs.

Comment: What information are you trying to get from the spooled file?  An AFP fIle has an intricate format.  If you only need textual data, the [CPYSPLF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/cpysplf.htm) command gets rid of fonts, barcodes, overlays, and images to leave only the textual data.  You can dump the results into a QTEMP library and parse it simply.